# Android - what are some common techniques to make phone apps not appear stretched on tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a few Android apps. They look on on the phones, but when I look at them on a tablet, they look very stretched (in width).  Here is an example screen shot:
[image]

Is there a particular design setting I can use to make the content and buttons not appear so stretched out when viewed on a tablet?  Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a technique, you just need to follow the guidelines that can be found on the Android developer site.

Comment: What does the term "design setting" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare I had in mind by that something like a specific max width that should be set, or something like that. It was just a thought.  But I am not sure hardcoding a max width is the best way to go.

Comment: @Luksprog Thank you - is there a link where this issue is discussed?

Comment: "I had in mind by that something like a specific max width that should be set, or something like that" -- meaning that you'd then just have a bunch of whitespace on the side? "is there a link where this issue is discussed?" -- thousands. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html... and those are just the ones in the official docs.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you look for. I was referring to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (or the fragments API) and it wouldn't hurt to have a look at http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Comment: Thanks :) looking now...

Comment: Do you want multiple columns? A single column with tons of white space, nothing in particular looks stretched, just spread out.